# A simple code to change image take 2 seconds to work, why

Tags: android, image, android-studio, android-drawable

Any idea why changing image takes so long, all the things change fast but this is waiting a little for apply changes.

I heard about invalidate() but coudn't find use for it...
If it's a solution how do I apply it to my code?
Where exactly do I put the code?

```
       baldeAzul.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if (portaAberta == false) {

                quartoFundo.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(FaseUm.this, R.drawable.quartofechadoazul));
            } else {

                quartoFundo.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(FaseUm.this, R.drawable.quartofechadoopenazul));
            }


        }
    });
```

Comment: `invalidate()` won't help you here. How big are your images? Each time you set them, you're loading them anew. If they're sizable, that can take some time. Can you scale them down? In either case, you could load the drawables ahead of time, so that all you're doing in `onClick()` is the `setImageDrawable()` calls, and not calling `getDrawable()` on every click.

Answer (score 1):

Your images are propably too large. One way is to manually rescale your image with an ecternal image editor like photoshop.

(Recommended)Another way is to make your image a bitmap and rescale it automatically based on the size of your imageView.
[Try this](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html)